# How to add thickness to a curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

How can I add thickness to a curve? I already tried with the extrude and depth options in the curve settings, but it doesn't work properly.

[image: beveled curve]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is set the *Fill* to *Full* on the curve to get a complete 3D shape. It defaults to *Half*, which is why you only have half of you shape showing.

[image: curve settings]

Comment: This is easier. Thickness is controlled by bevel depth and number of segments by bevel resolution.

Answer (score 8):

Add a nurbs circle and use it as bevel object:

[image]

You can control the thickness by scaling the circle.

Answer (score 8):

In Blender 2.8 Geometry / Extrude works for me

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do this is to use a *Solidify* modifier.

[image]

This is the result from the default Bezier curve.

[image]