# How could I create a 3 Dimensional scribble or doodle?

Tags: modeling, uv

I am trying to create a scribble drawing but make it spherical as if the pencil or pen lines are twisted within. I have tried to extrude planes and uv map a texture to those planes and unfortunately I lose dimension when planes are parallel to the camera view.

[image]

Any thoughts to approach this would be appreciated.

Comment: You might try using a curve object

Comment: I wrote a small plugin (not addon.. so this must be run from the text editor and it will add itself to the 3d view) -- https://gist.github.com/zeffii/9497c16760f36ed52d15 -- this auto rotates the 3d view to help with the grease pencil drawing -- unfortunately it's not continuous ..working on that...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could go about this.

## Curve object

1. Add a curve object (I used a path, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Curve > Path*)
2. In *edit mode* (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>), extrude a vertex around randomly (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> is a fast way to extrude a vertex many times)
3. Use the *Randomize* operator in edit mode to further increase randomness (<kbd>Space</kbd>*> Randomize*)

[image]

## Grease Pencil

1. Enable *Continuous Draw* in *3D view > Tool Shelf > Grease Pencil* and press *Draw* to start drawing
2. Draw scribbles while rotating the view at intervals

[image]

Once you are satisfied with your scribble, convert it to a curve object with the *Convert* button in the tool shelf:

[image]

Comment: After adding a curve you'll have to give it some thickness (otherwise you won't be able to see its shadow). See how to do it here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22932/how-to-add-thickness-to-a-curve (check out a pink vertex's answer).

Comment: Thank You! I was thinking of extruding along a path may do the trick then adding some material and texture to rough it up.

Comment: Rough render and post effects from instagram http://tomstuder.tumblr.com/post/126561215317/scribble-blender3d

Comment: @tomstuder nice result. Looks like a charcoal sketch a bit. How you achieved this interesting texture?

Comment: Here is the blend file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmk3r0xpmxgpcev/scribble_revised.blend?dl=0

Comment: Here is the refined sketch ![Scribble](http://tomstuder.tumblr.com/post/126584030427/refining-a-scribble-blender3d)

Answer (score 3):

Use a long strand of hair with 2 or 3 children, then use one of the styling options to randomise them, ie curl, braids etc