# How do i create a Doodle art animation in Blender?

Tags: modeling, animation

I would like to create a Doodle art using blender and to give animations to the individual doodles. i want to a have Individual Doodle character to be animated...just like in relative manner.Please help me with this..

Comment: For doodle art see this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35591/how-could-i-create-a-3-dimensional-scribble-or-doodle

Comment: Thanks,But i want to a have Individual Doodle character to  be animated...just like in relative manner......

Comment: For animating see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/how-to-animate-multiple-lines

Comment: Let me try it.....keep up the good work Sir

Comment: Ha ve you looked at animating using the grease pencil? : https://vimeo.com/113610809 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCscGP4oVmY