# How can I add thickness to this animating curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have imported a LaTeX figure from a latex2Blender add-on that I downloaded. I then converted the figure from a mesh to a curve. I then added a build modifier to the curve. The curve animates itself nicely.

[image: animation]

However, I want there to be some thickness to the curve. I would prefer for there to be 2D thickness instead of 3D thickness if possible. In other words, I don't want to trace out the curve with 3D tubing. I tried everything in this post: [How to add thickness to a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22932/how-to-add-thickness-to-a-curve) , but nothing worked for me

Here is the file:

[image]

Comment: You want to have something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/61lOW.jpg

Comment: yeah that looks perfect for the end result of the animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object to bevel the curve. In this case a very very very tiny path.

Add a *Curve > Path* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). This will create 4 m tall NurbPath object.

In *Edit* mode, scale it down to `0.000001` (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) and 3x up again to make it thicker (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image: tiny path for bevel]

When it has the right size you can use it as a bevel object for the *Latex Figure.001* curve:

[image: curve bevel]

End result of the animation:
[image: curve bevel]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing this on the "a" and ended up with poor corners https://imgur.com/a/sPWyGex   . I also tried it on a "b" and ended up with some weird lookin end-tips : https://imgur.com/a/E5wa7zc

Comment: Hm. Which Blender version do you use? I've used 2.93.5 in the answer but just tried 2.83.9. There it results in an even worse shape.

Comment: So I upgraded from 2.93.1 to 2.93.5 and I'm still getting the messy tips. I noticed that in the first image you uploaded, your nurb path x y and z scales are all set to one while the x dimension is .000012. Whenever my x dimension is .000012, my x scale will always go to 0, even when I try using the lock button. It says it's 0 but when you click on it to expand, it's actually 0.000003  https://imgur.com/a/fixJKPf

Comment: I bet that you scaled the nurb path in *Object* mode. You can do this in *Object* mode but you need to apply the *Scale* with Ctrl+A afterwards to reset the scale to 1.000. I've scaled it in *Edit* mode. Then you don't need to apply the scale transformation and it will stay at 1.000.

Comment: Ok I got my Transform tab looking like yours and I'm still seeing the messy tips and corners. Would it be best for me to see your file at this point and see how it looks on my computer?

Comment: That's strange. I've added the file to the answer above. Just tested the scale in *Object* mode without applying the scale. It looks the same. But I wonder why the scale must be so small because I've tried with a letter (created a *Text* object, converted it to a mesh, then *Mesh Clean up  > Limited Dissolve* and removed the faces and converted it to a curve). The *Build* modifier builds this in a different way. But the text curve only requires a nurb path with a size of 0.005....?

Comment: so I downloaded your file and the "a" looks perfect on my screen. I imported another LaTeX figure, converted it to a curve, applied the build modifier, then added to its bevel object the same nurbsPath as  the one that the "a" had, and then mine still had messy and tips and corners.  Yeah I was able to animate a standard text object the same as my imported objects. I did what you wrote, but I didn't delete the faces. The curve built itself nicely, but after adding a new nurbs path with a new size and assigning it to the bevel object of the text curve, the tips and corners were also messy.